# Shorter code to define all relational operators

Tags: c++

If we want to make all the relational operators of a class based on a member that already has those operators, is there no shorter way to do it than this?

```
struct foo {
  some_class mem; //some_class already has all the relational operators
  //other members
}

//is there really no shorter way than to type these 6 functions?
bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem == rhs.mem; }
bool operator!=(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem != rhs.mem; }
bool operator<(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem < rhs.mem; }
bool operator>(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem > rhs.mem; }
bool operator<=(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem <= rhs.mem; }
bool operator>=(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem >= rhs.mem; }
```

Comment: Yes, there is: `using std::relops;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly (using underlying member for all functions), no.

However, you can use [boost::operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to decrease number of functions to implement:

```
struct foo: boost::less_than_comparable<foo>, boost::equality_comparable<foo>
{
   some_class mem; //some_class already has all the relational operators
  //other members
}

bool operator<(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem < rhs.mem; }
bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return lhs.mem == rhs.mem; }
```

Note, however, that other operators will be defined *in terms of foo*, rather than *in terms of `mem`ber*, i.e.

```
bool operator !=(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty short, but you could define them all in terms of say a compareTo() method that returns negative, zero, or positive, according a-b is negative, zero or positive:

- ==: compareTo() returns zero
- !=: compareTo() returns non-zero
- <: compareTo() returns negative
- >=: compareTo() returns >= 0.
- >: compareTo() returns positive
- <=: compareTo() returns <= 0

Note also that every even-numbered row in the above is the negation of the previous row.

Comment: Viable, but you'd have to write things such as: `if(a.compareTo(b) < 0)` instead of `if(a < b)`. You'd basically be writing the definition of the operator out every single time anyway.

Comment: @Zéychin No, you don't have to write any if statements at all. Just return the result of comparing compareTo() to zero as above. And you can use the last observation to reduce the cases from 6 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you try to stay clean of preprocessor usage for religious reasons, your code can be written like this:

```
#define CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(operator_token, type_token, member_token) \
  operator##operator_token(const type_token& a, const type_token& b) { \
    return a.member_token operator_token b.member_token; \
  }

#define CALL_THROUGH_COMPARISONS(type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(< , type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(> , type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(!=, type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(<=, type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(>=, type_token, member_token) \
  bool CALL_THROUGH_OPERATOR(==, type_token, member_token)

CALL_THROUGH_COMPARISONS(foo, mem)
```

This is what I would do if I had at least two classes that could use CALL_THROUGH_COMPARISONS, for one class, I wouldn't bother. But I would also think twice about the general design: if it forces me to do such stupid forwards, it's most likely a bit too complicated (KISS!).